# Cannot start new Django project

Tags: python, django, django-admin, pkg-resources

I already have a website running under Django. It is a full project with many applications. Now I want to start a new project, so I type

```
django-admin startproject exampleProject
```

But I receive an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin", line 5, in <module>
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3018, in <module>
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 614, in _build_master
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 627, in _build_from_requirements
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 805, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Django==1.7.3
```

My last project wasn't created, but was received through GIT. Python version is 2.7 and Django version is 1.6, and I cannot upgrade them (because of reasons :-( ).
Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Have you tried removing  Django from your system and reinstalling? Also are you use a virtual environment, if not you should, if nothing else it isolates issues like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I have something. Apparently, I must have installed two Djangos. I don't know how I did it, but I did. After uninstalling one, I still received the same mistake, so instead of

```
django-admin startproject exampleProject
```

I typed in

```
django-admin.py startproject exampleProject
```

and it worked. At least, it seems so...